# Push Notification with Urbanairship

Tags: ios, push-notification, urbanairship.com

Im developing an iOS app that has a feature of Push notifications. Its a sports app where a user can add players to their favorites list. Each player has 3 kinds of events.

Like,

1. score a Goal
2. got a red car from referee
3. got a yellow car from referee

Now in this scenario,

- User X has configured player A for all 3 types

  User Y has configured player A for first 2 types

  User Z has configured player B for last 2 types

Now Server receives an update for Player A scores a Goal(1st type).

What exactly should be the payload?

I have tried the following

{"aps": {"badge": "+1", "alert": "Player A scored a Goal 10K", "participantID":["A"],"tags":["score a Goal"]}, "aliases": ["sportEvent2013"]}

At present im broadcasting the update, that is every device configured with APNS receive the push and only the one which matches the tag and participantID is displayed.

It does work, but i think this is not appropriate like every device receive the updates which can be in thousands, (im not using device token) because i can not tell who has configured for which events?

Please help me with the right approach.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you are also using the server side api for urban airship?

Comment: @Msencenb you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give more details if you give more details about your setup (all client, server component, etc). However the general idea should be to use the 'Tags' feature by urban airship (you can use alias too.. but that's not as flexible):

[UAirship Tags](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Client%3a+iOS%3a+Push#ClientiOSPush-SetTags)

The general concept is to 'subscribe' a user and their device token to a tag such as "PlayerAGoalScored". And then when that update comes through you can just tell urban airship to send a push to everyone subscribed to the tag 'PlayerAGoalscored"

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, I was wondering will that push be broadcasted to all the devices and then the one with the tag "PalyerAGoalScored" stored locally will display the alert.Because how can Urbanairship know which devices has set "PlayerAGoalScored" tag.

Comment: So the app will have to register the device as having tag 'PlayerAGoalScored', which then gets sent up to UAirship's servers. Now when you say to push a notification to tag 'PlayerAGoalScored' only the devices that have registered with that tag get pinged.

Answer (score 0):

You could set it up so that when a user configures a player to receive a particular type of notification, the app updates your database. Then, when the server receives an update for a player, query your database for those who have that flag set and send the notification only to them.